# Placing footer at bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I am using separate header.php and footer.php files which I include in the pages I want to place them in. now my header works well but my footer doesn't stick to bottom of page and when I tried to fix it by setting `position: fixed;` it takes in some portion of my content means covers some of content.

```
 *{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 background-color: #eeeeee;
 }
 .logo img {
  background-image: url(../img/menu_bg.png);
  width: 150px;
  height: 38px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  }
 .search_box {
   color: #198C9E;
   background-color: #198C9E;
   position: absolute;
   top: 6px;
   margin-left: 155px;
 } 
.headerMenu{
 background-color:#5DBEDE;
 }
 #wrapper {
 background-color:#5DBEDE;
 }
.footer {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 width:100%;
 height: 80px;
 background-color:#5DBEDE;
}
```

For test purposes, my footer.php is empty

```
 <?php 
  include ( "./inc/connect.inc.php" ); ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
   <title>test</title>
   <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css"/>
   </head>
    <body>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: You have to set height of html & body to 100%: `html, body { min-height: 100%; }`

Comment: And what does it have to do with PHP tag?

Comment: Agreed with @CDF , nothing related to PHP. I have checked it in fiddle, looks like working fine. footer comes at the bottom.

Comment: `body { margin: 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

add `padding-bottom: 80px;` to content block, while position fixed.
If think globally, and content height more than screen height:

```
.content {
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}
body {
    position: relative;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a very good way to put the footer at the bottom of the screen.

```
<div class="Content class">
  content will go here.
</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

The Stylesheet

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Note: The main logic to add the footer at the end and add the style mentioned to it. For HTML and body add the style.

Answer (score -2):

If you want the footer to stick to the bottom, no matter if the content is tall enough, you should use:

```
.footer{
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0;
 width:100%;
 height: 80px;
}
```

Since your footer has a fixed height, you can use for body:

```
body{
 padding-bottom:80px
}
```

This way you make sure the content does not get cut of.
See example here https://jsfiddle.net/05zh0j6u/

Comment: This places the footer at the bottom of the viewport at all times - if your data's calculated height is higher than the viewport, the footer will always display.